# The various ways of saying "all"

Tags: word-choice

While trying to write a plugin to (unofficially fan-)translate this website to Japanese, I've been noticing that "all" has multiple different translations.

What exactly is the difference between `全部（の）`, `すべて（の）`, `あらゆる` and `全体（の）`?

These are the translations I've currently come up with, but I don't know if they're correct:

- "all tags »"/"all badges »" links on the right panel of the "Top Questions" page: 
  `すべてのタグ »`/`すべてのバッジ »`
- "All Questions" page: 
  `すべての質問`
- The "all sites" tab in the Stack Exchange popup (in the top left corner): 
  `すべてのサイト`

What would be the difference between `全部のサイト`, `あらゆるサイト`, `すべてのサイト` and `全体のサイト`?

Comment: Don't forget `一切【いっさい】`!

Comment: Hmm, 一切 sounds a bit bookish to me, and I think it's more likely to be followed by a negative verb, like 一切知りません./一切責任を負いません。

Comment: I also remembered `何もかも` and `ことごとく`.  They also mean "all" in some way or another.  Maybe @Chocolate or fefe could update their answer to include these.

Comment: @istrasci san, Ah yes these two also mean 'all/everything'. And... they're adverbs...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [goo dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/119767/m0u/), すべて and 全部 are interchangeable in a lot of situations. However, すべて may be used more in articles, and 全部 more in conversations (「すべて」は文章語的で、「みな」「全部」は口語的である。).

あらゆる may be more like "every" instead of "all".

全体のサイト is a wrong expression in my opinion. 全体 means the "entire entity", but not a collection. E.g. その旅行全体にわたって (during the entire trip/all through the trip).

Comment: ah, I see! When I searched for `すべてのサイト` and `全部のサイト` they both had lots of results, but `全部のサイト` was indeed almost always used informally. I thought that was the case for `あらゆる` and `全体`, but my dictionary (Kodansha's Furigana dictionary) listed them all together under the subheader "totality" so I thought I'd check.

Comment: I thought that Sino-Japanese words (like 全部) are normally more likely to be used in writing? Perhaps it's just a misconception on my part.

Comment: @Flaw san, Ahh! Yes 全部 is more colloquial than 全て, while 全部 looks Sino-Japanese and 全て Japanese-origin... didn't notice that, how curious...

Answer (score 4):

> - "all tags »"/"all badges »" 
>     `すべてのタグ »`/`すべてのバッジ »`
> - "All Questions" page: 
>   `すべての質問`
> - The "all sites" 
>   `すべてのサイト`

I think all these are the best translations.

As fefe said, 全部の sounds more colloquial and less formal than 全ての.
あらゆる is more like 'every~/every single~' than 'all.'
全体 is like 'the whole ~', like 「このページ全体」= 'this whole page'.  

Maybe you could write it in kanji (全ての), btw.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe something for another question, but I wonder what the difference between `全て`, `凡て`, `総て` and `総べて` is? I've been noticing the different Kanji when searching.

Comment: @cypher Definitely an interesting question, but I think it merits its own question.

Comment: Lol, what a tough question. I'll have to check some Japanese dictionaries at home.

Comment: @Chocolate: Thank you, I couldn't figure out how to word `あらゆる` do I didn't post an answer.  But you said what I was wanting to say.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I wish I could accept both of your answers!